# Move element in a grid layout with arrow keys

Tags: javascript

I'm in the process of creating a turn-based game. For the moment I have a 16*16 grid. I have an event listener for all four arrow keys. I have placed a circle in the first grid item.
I want to move circle with arrow key one grid cell at a time.
I can't get my head around how can I do this. I think I should have a variable that will keep track of the circle. But how to move it to another cell on key-down?

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".grid");
const gridNodes = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item");
const gridArray = Array.from(gridNodes);
let circle = document.createElement("div");


function makeGrid(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty("--grid-rows", rows);
  container.style.setProperty("--grid-cols", cols);
  for (let c = 0; c < rows * cols; c++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    container.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item";
  }
}
const keys = {
  left: 37,
  up: 38,
  right: 39,
  down: 40
};
makeGrid(16, 16);
circle.style.width = "20px";
circle.style.height = "20px";
circle.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
let firstGridItem = document.querySelector(".grid-item");
firstGridItem.appendChild(circle);
function moveRight(e) {
  console.log(gridArray);
}
function handleKey(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case keys.left:
      console.log("left ");
      break;
    case keys.up:
      console.log("up ");
      break;

    case keys.right:
      moveRight(e);
      break;

    case keys.down:
      console.log("down ");
      break;
  }
}
window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKey);
```

```css
:root {
  --grid-cols: 1;
  --grid-rows: 1;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Turn Base Game</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bundle.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="text-center text-white">Turn Based Board Game</h1>
    <main class="map">
      <div class="container grid"></div>
    </main>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice problem.

1. First assigned co-ordinates to each box.
2. Added class based on the co-ordinates (e.g. grid-item-01, grid-item-02 etc)
3. Maintained position of current cursor (initially {x: 0, y: 0})
4. For each key press, handled position object and rendered the circle.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".grid");
const gridNodes = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item");
const gridArray = Array.from(gridNodes);
let circle = document.createElement("div");
let position = {x: 0, y: 0};


function makeGrid(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty("--grid-rows", rows);
  container.style.setProperty("--grid-cols", cols);
  
  let x = 0;
  let y = 0;
  for (let c = 0; c < rows * cols; c++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    
    y = c%cols;
    
    if (y === (rows - 1)) {
     x++;
    }    
        
    container.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item grid-item-" + x + '' + y;
  }
}
const keys = {
  left: 37,
  up: 38,
  right: 39,
  down: 40
};
makeGrid(16, 16);
circle.style.width = "20px";
circle.style.height = "20px";
circle.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
let firstGridItem = document.querySelector(".grid-item");
firstGridItem.appendChild(circle);

function handleKey(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case keys.left:
      position.y--;
      break;
    case keys.up:
      position.x--;
      break;

    case keys.right:
      position.y++;
      break;

    case keys.down:
      position.x++;
      break;
  }
  
  let gridItem = document.querySelector(".grid-item-" + position.x + '' + position.y);
  gridItem.appendChild(circle);
}
window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKey);
```

```css
:root {
  --grid-cols: 1;
  --grid-rows: 1;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Turn Base Game</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bundle.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="text-center text-white">Turn Based Board Game</h1>
    <main class="map">
      <div class="container grid"></div>
    </main>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well It will take time for me to understand the logic behind, but I do notice that it will throw an error when circle is on the boundaries. For example, at (0,0) if you hit keyup or keyleft it will throw error.

Comment: @Mehmood Yes. ... these are edge cases which you can fix easily

Comment: thanks @AdityaBhave this saved my day, this is nice logic. solve the edge cases using the below logic.

let position = { x: 0, y: 1 };

for (let c = 0; c < rows; c++) {
    for (let d = 1; d <= cols; d++) {
      let cell = document.createElement("div");
      container.appendChild(cell).className =
        "grid-item grid-item-" + c + "" + d;
    }
  }